# How to select multiple values (features) in separate columns (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, select-by-attribute, select-by-expression

Two parts to this question.

**Part 1**
I'm trying to *select by expression* all rows (features) that have a particular value across multiple columns. So, for example, I want to select all features that have a value of 'red' in the following table:

| Row number | Common Color | Favorite Color | sample color | guess color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **red** | blue | blue | blue |
| 2 | blue | blue | blue | green |
| 3 | green | *yellow* | **red** | *yellow* |
| 4 | blue | **red** | blue | blue |
| 5 | *yellow* | blue | *yellow* | **red** |

So in this scenario, I would want to select all row except row 2.

I've tried the following but but they haven't worked:

```
@feature IN ("common color", "favorite color","sample color","guess color") IS 'red'
```

```
@feature IN ("common color", "favorite color","sample color","guess color") = 'red'
```

**Part 2** To make things more complicated, I need a separate query that can compare values across across the colums. So, for example I only want to select the rows that have red in one of the columns but not yellow in another column. In this scenario, only rows 1 and 4 would be selected.

I've tried this, but it hasn't worked:

```
@feature IN ("common color", "favorite color","sample color","guess color") IS 'red' AND
 @feature IN ("common color", "favorite color","sample color","guess color") IS NOT 'yellow'
```

```
@feature IN ("common color", "favorite color","sample color","guess color") = 'red' AND
 @feature IN ("common color", "favorite color","sample color","guess color") !='yellow'
```

Comment: @PolyGeo not sure why this question was closed. First sentence seems to imply two questions. In fact it is just one question. The problem is explained in two steps - first the general principle, than in the very constellation OP wants. As the accepted answer shows, a relatively short expression solved to problem. So I would say it is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @Babel In the absence of a marked question my reading was two questions where their two code attempts to solve each separately did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this expression (explanation below) to check if any of the attributes of the current feature contains the value `'red'`:

```
array_contains ((map_avals (attributes())), 'red')
```

Combine this with a [`case`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#case) condition to get what you want:

```
case 
   when array_contains ((map_avals(attributes())), 'yellow') then 0
   when array_contains ((map_avals(attributes())), 'red') then 1
else 0
end
```

[image]

You could even add further `when ... then` conditions - be aware of what the [documentation says](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#case):

> The conditions are evaluated sequentially, and if a condition is true,
> the evaluation stops, and the corresponding result is returned. If
> none of the conditions are true, the value in the ELSE clause is
> returned.

**Explanation:**

- [`attributes()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-contains) returns a key:value map (dictionary) of all attributes, like in your example: `{ 'Common Color': 'red', 'Favorite Color':'blue', 'guess color':'blue', 'id': 0, 'sample color':'blue' }`
- [`map_avals()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#attributes) returns an array of the values: `[ 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 0, 'blue' ]`
- [`array_contains()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-contains) returns true if the array contains the given value - thus for the array in the last example, it would return `true` for `'red'` (and also for 'blue' or `0`, but `false` for any other value)